# Count statement to pertain to only one instance

Tags: sql, count

Trying to count the number of providers but when I add more columns, like the location for example, it then gives me a miscount.  The script below gives me the accurate count but adding another column screws it up which.

This is the script i have that gives me the accurate count:

```
select pm.last_name + ', ' + pm.first_name Provider
      ,count(pe.rendering_provider_id) Encounter
from patient_encounter pe
inner join provider_mstr pm on pe.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id
inner join location_mstr lm on pe.location_id = lm.location_id 
where pe.create_timestamp between '20190801 00:00:00.000' and '20190831 23:59:59.999'
and pe.billable_ind = 'y'
and pe.enc_status = 'H'
group by pm.last_name, pm.first_name
order by Provider
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Did you forget to include your query?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using

Comment: Sample data is probably critical here.  Also, when you say adding another column to your group by, you get a miscount - what does that mean?